# Looking for a QGIS Architecture Diagram

Tags: qgis, diagram

I would like to know the architecture of QGIS: relationships between QGIS and other open sources, and what elements are implemented in the QGIS.

Usually, There is a diagram showing the architecture of a software such as arcobjects. Even it is simple like Geotools's architecture, it is useful to understand internal structure of a software.

Comment: Dont think the moderators will approve of this type of question. Did You check here: http://www.qgis.org/en/about-qgis.html

Comment: Do you have an example, as in links, of what you had in mind.  If we don't have one for QGIS I'm sure we could make one at some stage.

Answer (score 4):

Update on top: There is this [French language diagram by Thomas Gratier](https://github.com/webgeodatavore/qgis-class-diagram)

[image]

and there is this one by Tim Sutton (but it's old):

[image]

Comment: Can you give any references for this diagram? Is there an updated version available?

Comment: It used to be on the QGIS website but I think it has been taken down since it's so old. You can still find a reference online in this thesis written at the Univ of Zurich http://www.opengis.ch/publications/msc-thesis-uzh/html/

Answer (score 1):

As per your question (Like comparing  to Arc-objects UML diagram no such diagram exists or may be under processing)

But check out [this](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Redesign_of_QGIS_data_model) link it might be useful for you.

For [Architecture_ Roadmap](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Architecture_Roadmap). Hope it will help you..